# How can I change a file's encoding with vim?

Tags: vim, unicode

I'm used to using vim to modify a file's line endings:

```
$ file file
file: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
$ vim file
:set ff=mac
:wq
$ file file
file: ASCII text, with CR line terminators
```

Is it possible to use a similar process to change a file's unicode encoding?  I'm trying the following, which doesn't work:

```
$ file file.xml
file.xml: Unicode text, UTF-16, little-endian
$ vim file
:set encoding=utf-8
:wq
$ file file.xml
file.xml: Unicode text, UTF-16, little-endian
```

I saw [someone say](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/solaris-opensolaris-20/converting-utf-16-files-to-another-encoding-such-as-utf-8-630588/) that he could "set fileencoding=utf-8, then update and write the file, and it works," but I seem to be missing something, or else he was confused.  I don't know what he meant by "then update."

Answer (score 290, accepted):

From the [doc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_45.html#45.4):

> :write ++enc=utf-8 russian.txt

So you should be able to change the encoding as part of the write command.

Comment: updated documentation link: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_45.html#45.4

Answer (score 188):

Notice that there is a difference between

```
set encoding
```

and

```
set fileencoding
```

In the first case, you'll change the output encoding that is shown in the terminal. In the second case, you'll change the output encoding of the file that is written.

Comment: thank you! Apache was outputting utf-8, so was php, so the browser said, so vim said with `set encoding`, and still the pages showed mangled characters that were alright as iso-8859-1. using `set fileencoding` showed a pretty 'Latin1'

Answer (score 86):

While using vim to do it is perfectly possible, why don't you simply use iconv? I mean - loading text editor just to do encoding conversion seems like using too big hammer for too small nail.

Just:

```
iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 file.xml > file.utf8.xml
```

And you're done.

Comment: Plus, this can be easily scripted for more files. +1

Comment: Downside, iconv might not be easily available on Windows.

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza neither vim.

Comment: I'd say multiple "just install" downloads, with even a portable edition" constitutes "easily available".

Comment: @adriano-varoli-piazza No, iconv is available on Windows with Cygwin and  MingW, as @ coder-tim noted.

Comment: @mario No, Vim very easily available on Windows: http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc

Answer (score 62):

Just like your steps, setting fileencoding should work. However, I'd like to add one "set bomb" to help editor consider the file as UTF8.

```
$ vim file
:set bomb
:set fileencoding=utf-8
:wq
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it led me to learn more about the UTF byte order mark. However FYI, setting a BOM seems unnecessary/inadvisable for UTF-8 since it's not a fixed byte-length format like 16 or 32. See [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Working_with_Unicode) for an explanation and reference. It's not a problem (and even helpful) for vim, I just thought people should just be aware that it may cause compatibility issues elsewhere.

Comment: Is it `bomb` or `bom`, and can it be `unset`? **EDIT**: Yes, you can remove it via `set nobomb`.

Comment: Yes, VIm set up us the `bomb` (with a b).

Comment: per the docs, `:set bomb` is turned on if `:set fenc=utf-8`.. see `:he bomb`

Comment: all our base encoding are now belong to UTF-8

Answer (score 8):

It could be useful to change the [encoding](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'encoding') just on the command line before the file is read:

```
rem On MicroSoft Windows
vim --cmd "set encoding=utf-8" file.ext
# In *nix shell
vim --cmd 'set encoding=utf-8' file.ext
```

See [starting](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html), [`--cmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#--cmd).

Comment: The first variation should also work on *nix shells. `'single quotes'` are only needed to escape all meta characters, which is usually not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

auto GUIEnter * set encoding=utf-8
should help