# Vim doesn't support unicode?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get the following into my .vimrc

```
" Use the same symbols as TextMate for tabstops and EOLs
set listchars=tab:▸\ ,eol:¬
```

Those lines are from [here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/show-invisibles/) are worked perfectly in vim 7.2
I recently compiled and installed vim 7.3 and now those characters aren't understood by vim.
Also: Ctrl+V then U in insert doesn't let me insert any characters, it just seems to ignore that.

Any ideas?

This is what I see: 
`set listchars=tab:�~V�\ ,eol:¬`

Comment: Are you using a Unicode capable terminal or gvim?

Comment: Yes I am. I am using screen, but I can paste those characters into it just fine.

Comment: Though Vim supports unicode, both MS and Linux systems don't have unicode support, I mean their terminals and consoles. Hence, I have installed vrapper in eclipse. Now, I am able to type in Unicode. :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to compile vim with multi-byte support.

The easiest way to do this is to run

```
./configure --with-features=big
make
```

This will build vim with the correct support.

You can verify that it was compiled correctly with

```
:version
```

in vim or by running

```
vim --version
```

and looking for `+multi_byte`.  If it says `-multi_byte` it will not work.

Comment: I had been kicking myself for the past couple days, trying to get vim-powerline symbols to work with fancy characters. This finally fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I installed arch linux the other day and my arrow symbols and tmux borders were messed up. This fixed vim, I think locale fixed the rest

Comment: for those still struggling: you also have to make sure your terminal is also set to use unicode : )

Answer (score 30):

I have the following in my .vimrc

```
scriptencoding utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
```

and that in my .gvimrc

```
set listchars=trail:·,precedes:«,extends:»,eol:↲,tab:▸\
```

and works fine(notice there is a space after the ▸\ ).

Comment: interesting, on linux i don't have to set anything. on vim win32 with +multi_byte i started to have to add it after i changed something in my vimrc... now, putting those two lines will not raise an error, but the trail chars render as a question mark or something else... if i leave ONLY `set encoding=utf-8` then it works as before

Comment: Remember to `set list` to enable listchars.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with the vim that ships with OS X Lion although it was compiled with `multi_byte`.

The issue was the encoding used by vim. I added `set encoding=utf-8` in my `~/.vimrc` and the issue was solved.

Ref: [Terminal Vim redraw issues in OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969965/terminal-vim-redraw-issues-in-os-x-lion)

Comment: Perfect. I share a vimrc between Mac and Windows using Dropbox. Worked perfectly fine with MacVim but Gvim on Windows was giving me errors upon startup.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you're using a compatible font. My problem was that inconsolata-g does not support the utf-8 characters in my document.

also, this was all I needed in my gvimrc:

```
set enc=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf8,prc
set guifont=Monaco:h14
set guifontwide=NSimsun:h14
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue while being in a `screen` session.
It's gone with setting the following in my `.bashrc`:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget, if you're running vim in a terminal, make sure the terminal itself is using utf-8 as well.

Answer (score 2):

When all else failed, telling vim to [save with UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/778105/706561) seemed to work (for now at least):

```
:write ++enc=utf-8
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a

```
scriptencoding utf-8
```

or whatever encoding your `.vimrc` is actually in?

Comment: Also, check the values of `encoding`, `termencoding`, `fileencoding` options.  Ensure that when you are editing `.vimrc` all of them are set to `utf-8`.

Comment: I've added it and it still doesn't work. How do I check the value of those other options?

Comment: You can see the value of any option by adding a ? after the set command. ie :set encoding?

Comment: Woah weird! Apparently the "encoding" option is not supported. I typed ":set encoding?" and that's the error that I got.

Comment: You must have a version of vim compiled with +multi_byte. The vim version must be B (Big), H (Huge) or a manually compiled with the +multi_byte flag. Check your build flags via :version

Comment: Yes! This ended up being the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. Working off of the downloaded [source](https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/) on a Mac running Lion, I went into the `src` directory and ran:

```
make clean
export CONF_OPT_MULTIBYTE='--enable-multibyte'
make reconfig
```

Running: `./vim --version` to check for `+muti_byte` then:

```
make install
```

Via: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/compiling-vim7-1-huge-version-gets-build-with-normal-version-td1162314.html