# As a vimer, how could I disable cscope jump to the first error in quickfix list when search?

Tags: vim

As a vimer, how could I disable cscope jump to the first error in quickfix list when search? Because it is not the case I want. I want to select it by myself.

I search everywhere, but until now there is not a satisfactory answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "m"?

Comment: A "vimer"? What's a "vimer"? I use Vim all day long but I'm a vim-user.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed.  I'd like to know how to do this too.  So far my research indicates that it's not possible, however.

Comment: hi, Jim. I have solved at the bottom. you could do it as what I pointed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Re-Cscope-quickfix-not-jump-to-first-error-td1193959.html

while at lase i merged the if_cscope_bang.patch and it's OK now.

when complie the vim

[Vim doesn't support unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766204/vim-doesnt-support-unicode)

also help me about my multi-byte support problem

Comment: Thanks for the link. It worked with vim8 too...

Answer (score 0):

Do you use cscope-specific `:cs find foo` or do you merge cscope with ctags and use `:cstag foo`?

Anyway, the default behavior is to not use the quickfix at all: both commands open a special window with a list of matches, even if there's only one match, and no jump is performed.

Check the value of `cscopequickfix` and read the associated doc `:help cscopequickfix`.

Comment: well,it's right. the value of cscopequickfix sets as follow:        set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e- .  with the setting,is there any way to solve the default jump problem.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be configurable. There are ways, in other contexts, to use the quickfix without jumping to the first error: `:make!` or `vimgrep /foo/j *` but I don't know of a way to do that here or of a global setting. Sorry. If you don't like that behavior, you should revert back to the original.