# CONVERSION ERROR in vim

Tags: vim

Adding `set listchars=tab:▸\ ,trail:·,extends:#,nbsp:·` line is causing "CONVERSION ERROR" while saving the vimrc file.
I am using gvim 7.3 under Window 7.

I have added this character using ("▸") using ctrl-vu 25B8.

my vimrc file has also `set encoding=utf-8`

Is it possible to resolve this error.

Thanks

Comment: Got the fix, I need to place a space character after ▸\ like ▸\ , 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766204/vim-doesnt-support-unicode

Comment: I had the same problem. @IngoKarat's answer solved it. I was trying to use `˒` as my tab char. It's a little more inconspicuous. :D

Answer (score 54):

Try saving with `:w ++enc=utf-8`. Also, it's recommended to put `scriptencoding utf-8` at the top of your `.vimrc`.

Comment: saving file using w ++enc=utf-8 way resolve the error.

But doing :so $MYVIMRC giving
E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:¿\,trail:·,extends:#,nbsp:.

Comment: @dearvivekkumar Don’t forget about the second advice with `scriptencoding`. I would also suggest to be sure there is `set encoding=utf-8` somewhere at the very top of the vimrc.

Comment: Awesome! This answer was the solution.

Comment: This solved my problem. I think it's because the unicode character appear near the end of a very large file that vim initially thinks the file's not in utf-8.

Comment: Unfortunately if `":echo has("multi_byte_encoding")` returns 0 then neither `set encoding=utf-8` nor `scriptencoding utf-8` can help you

Answer (score 7):

I solved this error (although not from listchars) by changing the buffer's encoding and then saving:

```
:set fileencoding=utf-8
:write
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from the link below, As I need to put a single space after ▸\ charter
[Vim doesn't support unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766204/vim-doesnt-support-unicode)