# Render combining characters separately in Emacs and Vim

Tags: vim, unicode, emacs, sublimetext2, combining-marks

By default, Sublime Text renders combining Unicode characters as separate characters.

For example,
the string `"a̅c"` (`U+0061`, `U+0305`, `U+0063`) is displayed as: [combining rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Zv1.png) (in the body, not the tab). Is there a way to duplicate this behavior in Emacs? In Vim?

Comment: @Elisha you incorrectly edited that Unicode sequence. The combining overline should be over the a, not the c.

Comment: @Elisha This actually looks like a browser rendering issue. My browser renders the overline over the c, but checking the page source shows the bytes in the correct order.

Comment: What is sublime? Did you mean subline?

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3766204

Comment: Sublime: https://www.sublimetext.com/.
And no, my vim is compiled with multibyte support. Multibyte support isn't the issue. I think you are confusing combining Unicode characters with multibyte encodings.