# How to print wstring on Linux/OS X?

Tags: c++, unicode, wstring

How can I print a string like this: `€áa¢cée£` on the console/screen? I tried this:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <string>
using namespace std;

wstring wStr = L"€áa¢cée£";

int main (void)
{
    wcout << wStr << " : " << wStr.length() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which is not working. Even confusing, if I remove `€` from the string, the print out comes like this: `?a?c?e? : 7` but with `€` in the string, nothing gets printed after the `€` character.

If I write the same code in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

wStr = u"€áa¢cée£"
print u"%s" % wStr
```

it prints out the string correctly on the very same console. What am I missing in c++ (well, I'm just a noob)? Cheers!!

---

**Update 1:** based on n.m.'s suggestion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string wStr = "€áa¢cée£";
char *pStr = 0;

int main (void)
{
    cout << wStr << " : " << wStr.length() << endl;

    pStr = &wStr[0];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < wStr.length(); i++) {
        cout << "char "<< i+1 << " # " << *pStr << " => " << pStr << endl;
        pStr++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

First of all, it reports `14` as the length of the string: `€áa¢cée£ : 14` Is it because it's counting 2 byte per character?

And all I get this:

```
char 1 # ? => €áa¢cée£
char 2 # ? => ??áa¢cée£
char 3 # ? => ?áa¢cée£
char 4 # ? => áa¢cée£
char 5 # ? => ?a¢cée£
char 6 # a => a¢cée£
char 7 # ? => ¢cée£
char 8 # ? => ?cée£
char 9 # c => cée£
char 10 # ? => ée£
char 11 # ? => ?e£
char 12 # e => e£
char 13 # ? => £
char 14 # ? => ?
```

as the last cout output. So, actual problem still remains, I believe. Cheers!!

---

**Update 2:** based on n.m.'s second suggestion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

wchar_t wStr[] = L"€áa¢cée£";
int iStr = sizeof(wStr) / sizeof(wStr[0]);        // length of the string
wchar_t *pStr = 0;

int main (void)
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL,"");
    wcout << wStr << " : " << iStr << endl;

    pStr = &wStr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < iStr; i++) {
       wcout << *pStr << " => " <<  static_cast<void*>(pStr) << " => " << pStr << endl;
       pStr++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what I get as my result:

```
€áa¢cée£ : 9
€ => 0x1000010e8 => €áa¢cée£
á => 0x1000010ec => áa¢cée£
a => 0x1000010f0 => a¢cée£
¢ => 0x1000010f4 => ¢cée£
c => 0x1000010f8 => cée£
é => 0x1000010fc => ée£
e => 0x100001100 => e£
£ => 0x100001104 => £
 => 0x100001108 =>
```

Why there it's reported as `9` than `8`? Or this is what I should expect? Cheers!!

Comment: What is the encoding of your source code file? ASCII?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331690/c-source-in-unicode

Comment: @selalerer: "encoding of the source file" - like `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in python? How do I know or set that in c++? I just use vim to write the script. Cheers!!

Comment: @Mac Every source file is just a text file. Every text file has some encoding, it can be some thing based on the ASCII table (in which every character is one byte) or UTF-8 or UTF-16 etc... Today every text editor supports saving the file in which ever encoding you choose. How to do this in vim? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778069/how-can-i-change-a-files-encoding-with-vim

Comment: @selalerer: this what it is: `uniTest.cpp: UTF-8 Unicode c program text`. I'd be surprised if it wasn't. The vim is being used in the very same way for every thing, whilst, e.g. python works but c++ not. Anything else do you thing still missing? cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Drop the `L` before the string literal. Use `std::string`, not `std::wstring`.

UPD: There's a better (correct) solution. keep wchar_t, wstring  and the L, and call `setlocale(LC_ALL,"")` in the beginning of your program.

You should call `setlocale(LC_ALL,"")` in the beginning of your program anyway. This instructs your program to work with your environment's locale, instead of the default "C" locale. Your environment has a UTF-8 one so everything should work.

Without calling `setlocale(LC_ALL,"")`, the program works with UTF-8 sequences without "realizing" that they are UTF-8. If a correct UTF-8 sequence is printed on the terminal, it will be interpreted as UTF-8 and everything will look fine. That's what happens if you use `string` and `char`: gcc uses UTF-8 as a default encoding for strings, and the ostream happily prints them without applying any conversion. It thinks it has a sequence of ASCII characters.

But when you use `wchar_t`, everything breaks: gcc uses UTF-32, the correct re-encoding is not applied (because the locale is "C") and the output is garbage.

When you call `setlocale(LC_ALL,"")` the program knows it should recode UTF-32 to UTF-8, and everything is fine and dandy again.

This all assumes that we only ever want to work with UTF-8. Using arbitrary locales and encodings is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: WOW!! that really works. That makes me asking another question: What does `wstring` (hence, also `wchar_t` I think) actually for then? Cheers!!

Comment: `wchar_t` is a nebulous type that is "big enough to hold any character from your system's character set", but it's entirely up to your platform what to do with that. Usually you have to interface it with the environment using `mbstowcs`/`wcstombs` functions, or `%Ls` in `printf`, etc. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability) for a little rant of mine on the subject, or [use C++0x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796157/unicode-encoding-for-string-literals-in-c0x) for explicit Unicode strings.

Comment: @n.m.: Well, I'm not really very sure now if it's really working: If I try something like this: `cout << *pStr << " => " << pStr << endl;` - it prints this: `? => €áa¢cée£` on the console. `pStr` is a pointer of type char. I've updated my original post with new my modified script. Cheers!!

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Thanks for the links. Is `C++0x` supported on any platform/OS? Cheers!!

Comment: C++0x is supported by GCC 4.3 and up, and by MSVS2010. Don't know about other compilers...

Comment: I have edited the answer with another suggestion, hopefully more correct than the previous one! I was in a hurry and didn't finish it properly the first time around.

Comment: @n.m.: I get: `error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token` on the setlocale(LC_ALL,"") line. I added this line right after the including the headers. Am I doing anything wrong? Most importantly, what does that error mean? Cheers!!

Comment: 1. You need to include an additional header, `#include <locale>` 2. You need to call `setlocale` inside the `main()` function. You cannot use statements at the file level in C++, only declarations are permitted there. The error is a bit cryptic. The compiler tried to interpet the statement as a declaration, but gave up in the middle. It says what kind of input it expected at that point.

Comment: aahhh...... I get it now. Although I already included the <locale> header, it's actually working without it for me. It almost worked, except one small problem: I just see another problem: a [white] space is being added to the end and `9` is being reported as the length of the string. Why this is happening? I've updated my original post with the new modification. Cheers!!

Comment: Hm, I don't know why you get 9 and a white space. I get 8 and no white space as expected. Perhaps you have a weird locale. What your `locale` linux command says, and also `echo $LANG` ? UPD: I know why, you're printing the terminating NULL character. Don't. Use std::wstring for simplicity, don't muck with C++ arrays and pointers and NULL-terminated strings.

Comment: `en_GB.UTF-8` is being reported (as I expect) for both `$LANG` and all the ENVIRONMENTs of `locale`.

Comment: I think, my `int iStr` calculation is wrong. if I change it to `wstring wStr = L"€áa¢cée£";` and `int iStr = wStr.length();` - everything works just fine as expected. Cheers!!