# wcout and wcerr: How to get it to work with unicode?

Tags: c++, macos, unicode, utf-8, io

```
#include <iostream>                           
#include <clocale>                            
#include <string>                             

int main() {                                  
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");     
    std::wstring str(L"Τὴ γλῶσσα μοῦ ἔδωσαν");
    std::wcout << str << std::endl;           
    std::wcerr << str << std::endl;           
}
```

This produces no output on the terminal.

How can I get it to produce UTF-8 output? I figure that ought to be something supported by C++.

I am aware of the [utfcpp](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) library, which I am using, but the question is specifically whether there is a stdlib way to print out UTF8.

Comment: This is platform-dependent. What're you running?

Comment: OS X here. I'll try this on Linux in a minute

Comment: Works flawlessly on Linux. Added osx tag.

Comment: Are you sure the terminal can display them?

Comment: Positive. I can view test files with lots of cool glyphs in them in Vim and echoing them through the shell.

Comment: If you're using UTF-8, why bother with `wchar_t`-related things?

Comment: @jamesdlin Excellent question. I have a different library which uses wstring internally for doing things. It happens to work well when given Unicode data, so there is no reason not to stick with it.

Comment: std::wcout works but not std::wcerr for me on centos 7.

Answer (score 0):

I got it by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6800471/340947).

`std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` is the magic incantation.

This worked on my trivial test program. However my full program still completely fails at printing out wstrings.

That is fine (well, no, it is still somewhat alarming), I will avoid relying on stdlib, and do it myself with the help of utfcpp library, which is excellent. This way I can use `cout` and `cerr` for everything and all will be well.