# C++ locale currency displaying - slavic currencies problem

Tags: c++, locale, currency, currency-formatting

I have to display some monetical values in c++ program using locale formatting. Everything works fine for locales such as `en_US` or `tr_TR`. In `pl_PL` and `cs_CZ` however, the result goes as follows: `1�235,45 zł`. I tried to identify the mysterious character using `thousands_sep()` method and it shows that the character code is `8239` what is absurd because it refers to the chinese charater 船. Is it how it's supposed to be or is it maybe a problem with my terminal? I'm using Manjaro Linux by the way.

Comment: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+202F

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Without it, it is hard to give you a useful piece of advice.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me solve my problem:
[How to print wstring on Linux/OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799762/how-to-print-wstring-on-linux-os-x)

As Hans Passant noted, that strange character is a narrow non-break space, which I had a problem with when I was trying to print it in the terminal.
According to the answer from the link above I put `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` at the beginning of my program and this helped - now all narrow non-break spaces, as well as other unicode characters, are printed correctly using both `std::cout` and `std::wcout`.