# Can I programmatically convert "Iâ€™d" to "I’d" using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, encoding

I can't seem to find the right combination of `String#encode` shenanigans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'd got confused on this one so I'll post this here to hopefully help anyone else who is similarly confused.

I was trying to do my encoding in an `irb` session, which gives you

```
irb(main):002:0> 'Iâ€™d'.force_encoding('UTF-8')
=> "Iâ€™d"
```

And if you try using `encode` instead of `force_encoding` then you get

```
irb(main):001:0> 'Iâ€™d'.encode('UTF-8')
=> "Iâ€™d"
```

This is with `irb` set to use an output and input encoding of UTF-8.  In my case to convert that string the way I want it involves telling Ruby that the source string is in `windows-1252` encoding.  You can do this by using the `-E` argument in which you specify `inputencoding:outputencoding' and then you get this

```
$ irb -EWindows-1252:UTF-8
irb(main):001:0> 'Iâ€™d'
=> "I\xC3\xA2\xE2\x82\xAC\xE2\x84\xA2d"
```

That looks wrong unless you pipe it out, which gives this

```
$ ruby -E Windows-1252:UTF-8 -e "puts 'Iâ€™d'"
I’d
```

Hurrah.  I'm not sure about why Ruby showed it as `"I\xC3\xA2\xE2\x82\xAC\xE2\x84\xA2d"` (something to do with the code page of the terminal?) so if anyone can comment with further insight that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I expect your script is using the encoding cp1251 and you have ruby >= 1.9.

Then you can use `force_encoding`:

```
#encoding: cp1251
#works also with  encoding: binary
source = 'Iâ€™d'
puts source.force_encoding('utf-8') #-> I’d
```

If my exceptions are wrong: Which encoding do you use and which ruby version?

---

A little background:
Problems with encoding are difficult to analyse. There may be conflicts between:

- Encoding of the source code (That's defined by the editor).
- Expected encoding of the source code (that's defined with `#encoding` on the first line). This is used by ruby.
- Encoding of the string (see e.g. section String encodings in http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/ruby-1-9-encodings/ )
- Encoding of the output shell

Comment: @ArupRakshit Is your output shell supporting UTF-8? And is your script code really encoded with cp1251?

Comment: I just copy pasted your code and ran in my Vim.. and got the output as I said above.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Can you the encoding you use in VIM (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778069/how-can-i-change-a-files-encoding-with-vim )